# If $b \cdot a = c\cdot a$ for equal-sized non-zero vectors $a, b, c$, does it follow that $c = b$?

Tags: matrices, vectors

I assumed $c = a$ due to transitivity. However, I read somewhere that this is only the case iff the vectors are collinear.

I hope someone can clear this up for me.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: What is going on? Why are you completely changing your question?

Comment: He thought this is a chat room :-)

Comment: @u9237an I rolled back the edits and restored the orginal question, What you did is not fair to the users who took the time and effort to post nice answers. You can ask the new one separately.

Comment: Sorry. New to mse, didn't realise this was not permissible. Thank you for retrieving the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not necessarily true. Think of your dot product as the projection of one of the vectors on the other multiplied by the latter.
Then for $a \cdot b$ let's say we have a projection of $b$ on $a$ multiplied by $a$, and for $a \cdot c$ we have a projection of $c$ on $a$. Note however, that we have a "free variable" - the angle between the vectors, which can be different in these two cases and thus it is not necessarily $b = c$.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you mean dot products?

If so, then consider $a = (1, 0, 0)$, $b = (0, 1, 0)$ and $c = (0, 0, 1)$.  All three different and of length 1, yet the dot products are the same (and 0).

(There are 2-d examples as well, but that's harder to construct.)